# Why is HDBSCAN considered a transductive clustering algorithm despite having approximate_predict?

Tags: clustering, predictive-models, unsupervised-learning, hierarchical-clustering, dbscan

In the [documents for HDBSCAN](https://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/prediction_tutorial.html) it says the following:

> Often it is useful to train a model once on a large amount of data,
> and then query the model repeatedly with small amounts of new data.
> This is hard for HDBSCAN* as it is a transductive method – new data
> points can (and should!) be able to alter the underlying clustering...
> We can accommodate this by effectively holding a clustering
> fixed...and then asking: if we do not change the existing clusters
> which cluster would HDBSCAN* assign a new data point to...just be sure
> to cache your data and retrain your model periodically to avoid drift!

This is implemented as `approximate_predict()` and `approximate_predict_scores`
More [documentation](https://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#hdbscan.prediction.approximate_predict) of these functions.

**Why is HDBSCAN considered a transductive clustering algorithm despite having functions which are clearly inductive/predictive aspects via the functions above?**